# Understanding the for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add each two values and return maximum of the sum from my function. And the following code works perfectly. The maximum sum is `14 => (3+4,3+4)`

```
function glassSum(arr) {
  let maxSum = 0
  for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
      const top = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j+1]
      const bottom = arr[i+1][j] + arr[i+1][j+1]
      const total = top + bottom
      if (total > maxSum) maxSum = total
    }
  }
  return maxSum
}
const a = [
  [1,2,3,4],
  [1,2,3,4],
  [1,2,3,4],
  [1,2,3,4]
]
glassSum(a)
```

But the fact I am not getting to the point is **why do I need the loop until 3 items**? While I expected it to work with `i<2,j<2` but it doesn't work. It only works if I have `i<3,j<3`. Can anyone please clear the concept?

Comment: @downvoter, please clear the concept and do downvote.

Comment: Explain why do you expect it to work with only 2 iteration

Comment: Not the downvoter but I see your loops have `<= 2` and your question states `< 2`. If you meant to type `< 2` in code too, then just trace it, it won't cover the entirety of the array.

Comment: @TSR It's because, `i=0, i=1` if I have `i < 2`, but if I have `i <= 2`, the `i=0,i=1,i=2`

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj Yes, that works. But I expected to work with `<2` instead.

Comment: Just trace the loop by hand, you will see why `< 2` won't work. This is a classic "off-by-one" error :)

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj If I do trace, I get the value i to be 0,1,2 and so on. Can you please clear with your answer?

Comment: You need `<=2` because you want to iterate `i+1` and `j+1` up to the highest index in the array, which is 3. The `2` in the loop condition has nothing to do with the fact that you want to sum 2 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input array is grid of size N= 4 (4X4)

Your function needs to cover all values of the grid.

Therefore, your number of iteration must be N-1
Which is 4-1=3

Hence, i<3 [0,1,2]

If you use i<2, you won't cover the last bottom right corner of your grid

For grid size 8 this print 36

```
function glassSum(arr) {
  let maxSum = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
      const top = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j+1]
      const bottom = arr[i+1][j] + arr[i+1][j+1]
      const total = top + bottom
      if (total > maxSum) maxSum = total
    }
  }
  return maxSum
}
const a = [
  [1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0],
  [1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0],
  [1,2,3,4,0,0,9,9],
  [1,2,3,4,0,0,9,9],
  [1,2,3,4,0,0,9,9],
  [1,2,3,4,0,0,9,9],
  [1,2,3,4,0,0,9,9],
  [1,2,3,4,0,0,9,9]
]
console.log(glassSum(a))
```

Comment: And what if I have 8x8, I still will need `<3` to sum two values. Can you explain this?

Comment: No, if N=8 ,you need N-1 iteration, which is 7 hence i<7

Comment: Makr sure your  input grid is 8 by 8. Count eight arrays have 8 elements each

Comment: It should be i < 7 and j < 7 , you have put i <= 8 and j <= 8 (less or equal to 8 means less than 9, < 9 ) since your grid size is 8, N-1 = 7

Comment: It works because you found the highest value without checking all the Grid. This is just coincidence that the highest value was found in the top 3 rows and column, but it won't work in all cases

Comment: if you are dealing with a biased input array, it may work with less than N-1 . But for a random distribution array, it will only work with N-1 loops. That being said, it is impossible to tell why it works with less than N-1 if you don't provide any information on how the input array is distributed. My answer here (and other answer) assumed that your input array has a random distribution

Answer (score 1):

Lets go over iteration here. We all know array index starts from 0.

For `j < 3`

1<sup>st</sup> iteration: `j = 0` [ j < 3 = true ]
2<sup>nd</sup> iteration: `j = 1` [ j < 3 = true ]
3<sup>rd</sup> iteration: `j = 2` [ j < 3 = true ]
4<sup>th</sup> iteration: `j = 3` [ j < 3 = false ] - The loop will exit

Hence you need `j < 3` for 3 iterations.